# run php code with javascript code using crontab in linux

Tags: php, linux, cron, phantomjs

I am trying to a php code which contain JavaScript code using phantomjs and firefox browser into crontab. But it's not working.If i run using CURL then it's run but js code isn't work.My crontab command below.

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/phantomjs http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/project/index.php > /dev/null 2>&1

* * * * * /usr/bin/firefox http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/project/index.php > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Someone tell me can i run php and js code into crontab?If yes then what is easier way?

Answer (score 0):

As [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), which is a **JavaScript based automation framework** available for Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, other *ix systems.

Using PhantomJS, you can do things like this:

```
    console.log('Loading a web page');

    var page = new WebPage();
    var url = "http://www.phantomjs.org/";

    page.open(url, function (status) {
        // perform your task once the page is ready ...
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

Or evaluate a **page's title**:

```
    var page = require('webpage').create();
    page.open(url, function (status) {
        var title = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.title;
        });
        console.log('Page title is ' + title);
    });
```

Examples from [PhantomJS' Quickstart](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart) page. You can even **render a page to a PNG, JPEG or PDF** using the [render()](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/Interface#render%28fileName%29) method.

so in your crontab

```
* * * * * /usr/local/bin/phantomjs /home/user/custom.js > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: so it means i can not run php code using  PhantomJS

Comment: for only PHP code use `* * * * * curl -0 http://XX.XX.XXX.XXX/project/index.php > /dev/null 2>&1`
`

Comment: but this will be executed without JS events